# Why is std::find( s.begin(), s.end(), val ) 1000x slower than s.find(val) for a set<int> s?

Tags: c++, find, set, std

I have recently started relearning C++ as I have not been coding in C++ for more than a decade. I have rarely used the STL, even when I worked at SGI, and I want to master it. I have ordered a book and I am currently running different online tutorials.

One tutorial introduced `std::find(begin(),end(),value)` and I was shocked at how slow it was in the test code I wrote. After doing some trial and error I found that `s.find(value)` was clearly what I should be using.

Why is the first find in the code so dramatically slow?

```
set<int> s;

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    s.insert(rand());

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    int r = rand();

    //first find is about 1000x slower than the next one
    auto iter1 = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
    auto iter2 = s.find(r);
}
```

EDIT: added timing experiment results

@juanchopanza asked about timing in the comments so I timed `std::find()` on Set, List, Vector and `set.find()`
(I only measured find - variation between runs was below 10%)

Vector performs much better than List or Set, but the specialized find from set wins with big data sets.

```
 Elements  Vector     List      Set    | Set.Find()
      10   0.0017    0.0017    0.0020  |  0.0017
     100   0.0028    0.0051    0.0120  |  0.0019
    1000   0.0105    0.0808    0.1495  |  0.0035
   10000   0.0767    0.7486    2.7009  |  0.0068
  100000   0.2572    2.4700    6.9636  |  0.0080
 1000000   0.2674    2.5922    7.0149  |  0.0082
10000000   0.2728    2.6485    7.0833  |  0.0082
```

Comment: `std::find` is O(n)  `set::find` is O(log n).

Comment: @Quimby I'd be curious behind the reasoning. It would be possible to provide SFINAE overload for `std::find` which would delegate the call to `container.find` for *tree* like containers.

Comment: @Zereges see my answer.

Comment: @Zereges: How would that work for arguments other than `begin, end` ?

Comment: @MSalters No one is preventing the iterator from keeping the reference to the underlying container. Implementation of `std::find` could do `if (__underlying_container_has_find_method) begin->find(val)`

Comment: @Zereges That wouldn't work with most containers due to iterator-invalidation-rules.

Comment: @Zereges actually as keeping reference to underlying container is not available by documented interface that prevents it to be used by `std::find` even if somebody would make that available

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::find` is a generic algorithm that given a pair of iterators can find a value. And if all it has been given is a pair of iterators the best way to find a value is just to linearly search for it which is O(n).

`set::find` is a member function of `std::set` and so it knows the data structure its searching over and so can optimise the search. And sorted, balanced trees have excellent searching behavoir of O(log(n))

Comment: That is exactly the clue I was looking for. Most of the tutorials I have been running use such small datasets that the container you pick does not matter. Clearly I need to learn the proper containers to use depending on my use case.

Comment: @Ves It would be interesting to see how an `std::vector` with the same data and `std::find` performs, compared to `std::set` with `std::set::find`.

Comment: And naturally a *sorted* `std::vector` will be better than either if you use `std::upper_bound`

Comment: @juanchopanza `std::vector` performs better than most people expect.  Have a look at the 10mins starting at 45:50 (take note of the peoples names) https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661

Comment: @RichardCritten You don't have to convince _me_ about it :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, didn't realise you were being rhetorical.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did an experiment with vector and it was significantly faster than set with std::find (0.1 seconds) - Set with std::find (2.7 seconds), set.find(.002 seconds).

Comment: @Ves If you're counting the time to fill the set and vector, then if you use `std::vector::reserve` it can be even faster. An interesting extension to the experiment is to find at which sample size the set starts overtaking the vector.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment.

Because `set::find` has more information about elements in the search range. It knows its (probably) implemented as a sorted binary tree and can search it in logarithmic time.

`std::find` on the other hand only gets two *bidirectional* iterators, so the best it can do is basically just a for loop.
<s>Had the set returned *random-access* iterator, `std::find` would have also been logarithmic.</s> 
EDIT: Corrected my wrong claims.

Comment: I don't see a reason why would `std::find` work differently for random-access iterators and bidirectional iterators and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) doesn't state that either. The complexity is *At most `last` - `first` applications of the predicate.*

Comment: @Zereges because you cannot do the standard binary search with them. Random-access allows to get the middle element in O(1). Bidirectional only supports incrementing and decrementing. So to get to the middle element you must iterate which is O(n) and in that case you might as well do the for loop.

Comment: And of course any decent STL implementation has different overloads for each iterator category exactly for these kind of optimizations. Try to replace `set` with `vector` and you should get same performance for both the `std::find` and `vector::find`

Comment: @Quimby Unclear what you're talking about. `std::vector` has no `find` member function.

Comment: @Quimby Binary search only works for sorted sequences. `std::find` works for unsorted sequences as well.

Comment: @Zereges oh... you are right, I don't know why I assumed it would know its sorted. Well in that case `std::find` is always linear. So Mike Vine's answer is more correct than mine.

Comment: @juanchopanza Damn, you are also right. Sorry to confuse you both. Feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The first reason is that `std::find` is specified in terms of linear search.  Meanwhile, `std::set.find` is specified in terms of logarithmic time search.

But if you replaced `std::find` with `std::equal_range`, which will do a binary search, you'll find it is as slow as `std::find`.

So I'll answer a better question than you asked:

## Why is `std::equal_range` ridiculously slow on set iterators?

Well, there really isn't a great reason.

`std::set` iterators are bidirectional iterators.  This means that they permit going forward one step, or backwards one step.

`std::equal_range` on bidirectional iterators is *extremely slow*, because it has to walk step by step through the range.

The `std::set.find` method, on the other hand, uses the tree structure of `std::set` to find the element really fast.  It can, basically, get midpoints of a range really fast.

C++ does not expose this tree structure when you access `std::set` via its iterators.  If it had, there might have been an operation like `std::somewhere_between( start, finish )` which would in O(1) time get an iterator between `start` and `finish`, returning `finish` if no such iterator exists.

Such an operation is actually really cheap on the tree structure implementation of `std::set`.

However this operation doesn't exist.  So `std::equal_range( begin(set), end(set) )` is ridiculously slow.

Possibly not exposing an operation like `std::somewhere_between` for sorted associative containers makes some set/map implementations more efficient; many used to use special nodes to replace some leaf cases.  And maybe you'd need access to that special node to efficiently binary search the tree.

But I seriously doubt it is worth the lack of that operation.  With that operation, you can work on a `std::set` or `std::map` subsection efficiently; without it, you got nothing.